# How to getExtra from previous activity to set different button intents?

Tags: android, button, android-intent, onclick, switch-statement

I want to pass extra to my NextActivity so that a button in NextActivity can have different intents. I am successful with doing this to view different layouts, but no clue on how to do this on a button.
Heres the code that has a working setContentView switch;

```
public class ContentViewer extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    int chooser = bundle.getInt("Layout");

    switch(chooser) {
    case 0:
        setContentView(R.layout.about);
        break;

    case 1:
        setContentView(R.layout.contact);
        break;

    case 2:
        setContentView(R.layout.contentviewer);
        break;

    case 3:
        setContentView(R.layout.contact);
        break;

    case 4:
        setContentView(R.layout.contact);
        break;

    case 5:
        setContentView(R.layout.contact);
        break;

    case 6:
        setContentView(R.layout.contact);
        break;

    case 7:
        setContentView(R.layout.contact);
        break;

    case 8:
        setContentView(R.layout.contact);
        break;

    case 9:
        setContentView(R.layout.contact);
        break;
    }
}
}
```

Now, in these layouts, there is a button with the same ID, but i want it to have different Intents based on different cases(like the setContentView above).

**UPDATE**
Theres MainActivity, it has a listview that passes extra. When an item in the listview is clicked, it will open the NextActivity(like in code). NextActivity has a layout that has a Button. Now, based on which item was clicked on the MainActivity, the Button will have different Intents. For example, if in MainActivity, item 1 was clicked, open NextActivity, override Button to have intent 1. If in MainActivity item 2 was clicked, open NextActivity with override button to have intent 2 INSTEAD of intent 1. Clear enough?

Comment: your question is not that much clear. Can you please elaborate little bit?

Comment: @thinksteep Theres MainActivity, it has a listview that passes extra. When an item in the listview is clicked, it will open the NextActivity(like in code). NextActivity has a layout that has a Button. Now, based on which item was clicked on the MainActivity, the Button will have different Intents. For example, if in MainActivity, item 1 was clicked, open NextActivity, override Button to have intent 1. If in MainActivity item 2 was clicked, open NextActivity with override button to have intent 2 INSTEAD of intent 1. Clear enough?

Comment: Got it. It is clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this you may need to be:

```
 int valueFromBundle = get value from bundle here...; 

 Button ipButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.my_button);

 ipButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               switch(chooser) { 
                case 0:
                Intent i = new Intent(fromActivity.class, toActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
                case 1:
                Intent i = new Intent(fromActivity.class, toActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
                etc..,



             }

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are already on the right track.

The first thing you will need to do is make sure your Button has an id in xml `android:id="@+id/my_button"`

Then after your setContent logic get a reference to that button:

```
Button myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.my_button);
```

You can then add a onClick listener to that button to handle user clicks:

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Your switch logic should go here!
            }
        });
```

In the onClick function you can add your switch logic, you might have a separate extra for this but that is up to you, you can essentially do the same as you did above but call a different intent instead of set the content.

Comment: I get error= "The method onClick(View) of new type onClickListener(){} must override a superclass method

Comment: Try getting rid of the @Override or set your project to use java language level 6.0.